# How can we visualize a multiple regression with >2 independent variables?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, data-visualization

An easy way to visualize a multiple regression with 2 independent variables is by a plane, as a plane is defined by 3 points that do not lie within the same line.

So we have the Y-intercept, the X variable (axis) and the Z variable (axis) to visualize three points making up a plane.

However a multiple regression is not limited to 2 independent variables. How do you visualize a multiple regression given, say, 3 independent variables?

Comment: The only way I know to do this for three independent variables is to make an animation. For example, one way to show how the relationship between X, Y, Z, and time is to make an animation displaying a surface changing over time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible to visualize a multiple regression with 2 predictors without using a 3D plot (which is implied by your discussion of the plane & Z-axis). Instead of the Z axis, we typically use colour to indicate variation in the extra dimension. The result is called a level plot (or a contour plot if contours are used instead of colour). Here's an example I found via google:

[image]

These plots are very useful but the term 'level plot' is not very well-known. It's possible that this goes by other names as well, but I'm not aware of them.

This plotting approach generalizes easily to 3 dimensions. Imagine that there was a third predictor in the model: `Sex`. In that case, just use one level plot for each `Sex`. Or imagine that the predictor is continuous, such as 'Daily Calorie Consumption' or `Consumption` for short. In that case, choose a small number of levels of `Consumption` (say 5) that meaningfully cover the range of values you are interested in. Use one level plot to convey the model-predicted `Age` x `Weight` interaction at each of these `Consumption` levels.

I have used this for 4 dimensions too, leading to a nice plot matrix. Beyond 4, I think its usefulness starts to break down. But 5-dimensional visualization is a major challenge, even though it's possible to use time (animation) as one dimension.

Comment: That's a very nice explanation. Did you ever write up something similar but explaining the mathematics of the regression and how they pertain to the colors/contours of each variable in multiple regression? I feel the mathematics is easy to understand in a univariate regression but as soon as we start adding independent variables I only get the idea but the big picture eludes me.

Comment: @Paze Thanks, glad it was useful. I haven't written an answer about the mathematics of multiple regression, but there might be something that addresses this already at the [tag:multiple-regression], so I would check there. If you don't find such an answer, I recommend posting a new question about this.